# What should I return from method if the object I want to return is not found?

Tags: java

Here's my method:

```
public Book getBook(String title, String author){
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.size(); i++){
        Book book = listOfBooks.get(i);
        if (book.getTitle() == title && book.getAuthor() == author){
            return book;
        }
    }
}
```

What should I return if the book is not found in the listOfBooks ?

Comment: what is problem with return `null`!! you can return null if no book found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning `null` (and documenting the behaviour) is one reasonably obvious choice.

P.S. Use `equals()` to compare strings:

```
if (book.getTitle().equals(title) && book.getAuthor().equals(author)) {
```

P.P.S. The following way to write the loop is arguably more idiomatic and in some circumstances could be considerably faster:

```
for (Book book : listOfBooks) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Either return `null` or throw a `BookNotFoundException` exception which you've written that inherits from Java.lang.Exception

Comment: +1, throwing an Exception can be very valid alternative here, depending if the condition is recoverable or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `return null;` if Book is not found or throw a custom `Exception` like 'NotFoundException`.

btw you must not use `==` for comparing String in Java. Use:

```
if (book.getTitle().equals(title) && book.getAuthor().equals(author))
```

instead of:

```
if (book.getTitle() == title && book.getAuthor() == author)
```

Comment: I had read in Effective Java, it is not a good habit to return null. Instead we can return an empty object, or throw an exception.

Comment: It entirely depends upon contract between caller and callee, But I also prefer returning a custom `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `null` if nothing is found and when comparing `String` use `equals()` method `book.getTitle().equals(title)` and `book.getAuthor().equals(author)` You can read about [comparing string with equals and assignment operator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/)

Answer (score 0):

I would either return `null` and write this behavior in the documentation of your class, or throw an Exception `BookNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

you can return null to say that you data is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can return null if the book object is not found in the list. And use .equals() method to compare the string.

```
  public Book getBook(String title, String author){
            Book book =null;
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.size(); i++){
                book = listOfBooks.get(i);
               if (book.getTitle().equals(title) && book.getAuthor().equals(author){
                  return book;
               }
           }
           return book;
   }
```